# How to modify views exposed form block in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a Drupal 8 site that uses the module :

https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation

I created a view with a group filter to select a distance in km with a field to enter an address.

The problem is that this filter is displayed incorrectly :

[image]

I would like to put the distance under the input field of the address and add a label above the distance selector :

**Adresse**

---

**Distance**

---

https://gist.github.com/jez500/4d1ef061e41f69a964732461cb0ec43a

Should you create a custom module or add a code to the file `.theme` ?

What is the code to put ?

Comment: You probably want to make use of a [HOOK_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.6.x) or [HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.6.x)

Comment: @2pha I do not know how to code this or if I have to create a custom module or my theme

Comment: Hooks invoke modules only so yes you need to implement it in a .module of your choice. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/243061